# How do you round off float values in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

In BallerinaLang, how do you round off float values to a specified number of decimal places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ballerina has not provided specific method yet for float round off. But using [math:round](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/math.html#round)  of existing [math package](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/math.html), following can be done.

```
import ballerina/math;

function roundFloat(float value, int decimalPlaces) returns float {
    float factor = math:pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    return  <float> math:round(value * factor)/factor;
}

function main(string... args) {
        float result = roundFloat(12.84675, 2);
}
```

PS: math:round function only rounds a floating point number to the nearest int