# Ballerina function to limit the decimal points in a float

Tags: ballerina

I want to limit the number of decimal points in a float value, I don't want to [round off the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51211525/how-do-you-round-off-float-values-in-ballerina) rather format it. Is there a specific method like [JavaScript toFixed()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) in Ballerina for this?

I'm using Ballerina 0.990.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `io:sprintf()`.

Eg -

```
float f = 123.4567;
// This will format the floating point number to 2 decimal points.
io:println(io:sprintf("%.2f", f));
```

More info on `sprintf` function is available at https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/io.html#sprintf